# Using UISwitch when moving from one

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiswitch

So I have a good animation showing on a tab bar, but I want to be able to allow the user to turn off the animation if they want.

```
//MainViewController.m

- (void) animateTabBar{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:(TAB_BAR_ANIMATION_TIME / 2) animations:^{
        CGPoint rightOffset = CGPointMake(self.tabBarScrollView.contentSize.width -    self.tabBarScrollView.bounds.size.width, 0);
        [self.tabBarScrollView setContentOffset:rightOffset];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:(TAB_BAR_ANIMATION_TIME / 2) animations:^{
            [self.tabBarScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        }];
    }];
}
```

I use this within my other code to actually make it move

```
[self animateTabBar];
```

How can I have this to be toggle with a UISwitch on my Settings so the user can turn this off.

Here's an abstract of how it should work, but obviously it's not working correctly.

```
// SettingsViewController.m

-(IBAction)onOffSwitch:(id)sender{

if(onOffSwitch.on) {
    // Animation is on
    [self animateTabBar];
}

else {
    // No animation
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like since this is a user preference, the correct place to save it would be in the NSUserDefaults, so you can try this in your settings:

The switch should be a "Not show animation", so when it is On, is not showing the animation, and initially would be Off(which shows the animation)

```
-(IBAction)onOffSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:sender.on forKey:@"ShouldNotShowAnimation"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

And in your animation, you can add

```
- (void) animateTabBar{
    if ([NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"ShouldNotShowAnimation"]) return;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:(TAB_BAR_ANIMATION_TIME / 2) animations:^{
        CGPoint rightOffset = CGPointMake(self.tabBarScrollView.contentSize.width -        self.tabBarScrollView.bounds.size.width, 0);
        [self.tabBarScrollView setContentOffset:rightOffset];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:(TAB_BAR_ANIMATION_TIME / 2) animations:^{
            [self.tabBarScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        }];
    }];
}
```

I added just one line, that checks in the user defaults and then quits (no animation) if "ShouldNotShowAnimation" is YES.

If it is no, then it will show the animation.  And since the boolForKey: returns NO if it cannot find the user default, it will show the animation if it has not been set before.

**EDIT**

To show the UISwitch correctly in the settings view, add this in the viewWillAppear method

```
self.switch.on = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"ShouldNotShowAnimation"];
```

Comment: Your solution is not completed. Show there how UISWitch should obtain its initial value on app's launch.

Comment: Good point, I'll edit assuming you want it initially to show the animation.

Comment: @rr1g0 This didn't work. I put the IBAction code into the settings view controller and tied it up with the storyboard. I also modified the AnimateTabBar and nothing happens. Also I can't get the UISwitch to stay on after tapping it.

Comment: did you tied it up with the "value change" event? are you using the same string on user defaults? I will add a code to show the switch as it should be

Comment: @rr1g0 wouldn't switch in  self.switch.on = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"ShouldNotShowAnimation"]; need to be a property of the SettingsViewController?